# Why does ($ 3) have signuature (a -> b) -> b?

Tags: haskell, partial-application, partialfunction

In *Learn you a Haskell*, it is given the following example:

```
map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
```

However, I don't understand why this works.

The signatures of the functions are

```
Prelude> :info ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
Prelude> :t ($ 3)
($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

However, `->` is a left-associative operator, so `$ :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` is actually `((($ :: (a-b))-> a)-> b)`, so shouldn't `3` in `($ 3)` correspond to `(a->b)` function that is the first "variable" of the function `$`? i.e why is `($ 3)` a function of signature `(a -> b) -> b`

Source: http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions

Comment: Don't use a polymorphic value `3`, try it with something concrete like `($ False)` or `($ ())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, `->` is a left-associative operator.

**No**, `->` is a *right-associative* operator. In the [*Learn You a Haskell* documentation](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#higher-orderism), it says:

> First of all, notice the type declaration. Before, **we didn't need parentheses because `->` is naturally right-associative**.

A more verbose version of the type signatures of `($)` and `($ 3)` are:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

we can write the type constructors in a more canonical form as:

```
($) :: (->) ((->) a b) ((->) a b)
($ 3) :: Num a => (->) ((->) a b) b
```

This thus means that `$` takes a function with signature `a -> b`, and thus returns a function with signature `a -> b`, it thus basically acts as `id`, except that it constrants the input to a function (and not just any type), and that you can use `$` easily whereas `` (`id` 3) `` is not that elegant.

If we thus apply `3` to the `f $ 3` operator, we know that `f` will have signature `f :: a -> b`, and `3` will have type `Num a => a`. If we work with operator sectioning with `($ 3)`, we pass `3` as the "second" parameter (in Haskell every function has exactly one parameter, but here we assign it thus to the parameter that is the result of `($) f`, this thus means that the type of `($ 3)` is `Num a => (a -> b) -> b`.

Comment: But if that is the case, when does the following valid:
`f :: Int -> Float -> Float; f x y = y; :t (f 2); Float -> Float`

Comment: Because `(f 2)` is *not* operator sectioning. `(f 2)` is simply `f 2`, so we call `f` with parameter `2`, and since `f` has type `f :: Int -> (Float -> Float)`, it thus returns a `Float -> Float` function.

Comment: I still don't get it: in the signature of `($)` is like `c -> a -> b` where `c` is `(a->b)`.
And when you do `$ 3`, 3 is not matched to `c` but rather to `a`.
But when in the case of the toy example above, it is the other way around

Comment: @Our: no when you do `($ 3)`, then it is interpeted as `\x -> $ x 3`, but `($) 3` is simply using `3` as parameter. See [*section of an infix operator*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator). `f` is not an (infix) operator, `$` is.

Comment: In other words `(/ 2)` will divide by two, whereas `(/) 2` will divide two by the parameter of that function, and `div 2` will also divide two by a parameter we are still missing.

Comment: For completeness, ``(`f` 2.0)`` and ``(2 `f`)`` *would* be an examples of operator sectioning. Putting a function name in backquotes lets you treat it like an operator.